# Lazy load Eloquent relation with parameter

Tags: laravel, eloquent, parameters, lazy-loading

I want to lazyload the products with a Laravel Eloquent Entity

```
/**
 * This is in my Orders model
 */
public function product($lang = '') {
    switch ($lang){
        case '':        return $this->belongsTo(ViewProducts::class, 'product_id', 'id');
        case 'en_us':   return $this->belongsTo(ViewProductsEnUs::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
/**
 * This is what works. But its not lazy
 */
$orders = Oders::where('email','me@me.com')
    ->get();

foreach ($orders as $order){
    $product = $order->products('en_us')->first();
}

/**
 * This is what I want. Lazyload the product in a different language 'en_us'
 */
$orders = Oders::where('email','me@me.com')
    ->with('products', // I want to pass the param 'en_us' in any way //)
    ->get();
```

Anybody out there who knows how to pass a param (in any way) to the Eloquent Entity so I can lazyload my product data?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you've got 2 different Models, you should probably just define two relationships, and do `->with($lang ? 'products' : 'enUsProducts')`. Are you able to just use a single table/Model, with a column to specify `$lang`? Then you could do `->with(['products' => function ($query) { $query->where('column', 'en_us'); }]) ...`

Comment: @TimLewis Dude! What a pragmatical solution! Thank you.. I got tunnel vision but defining more relations works of course as a charm!... ->with('products' . $lang)

Tnx again!

Comment: Oh nice! Glad you got it working, and good call with simple concatenation there :) Btw, feel free to add a self-answer below; it's the proper way to close off a question on Stackoverflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @TimLewis!

Instead of one relation 'product_' defining multiple relations like

```
/**
 * In my Orders model
 */
public function product_() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ViewProducts::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function product_en_us(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ViewProductsEnUs::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Works!

It's not totally perfect because you have to use it like so:

```
$productRelation = 'product_' . $lang;

$orders = Oders::where('email','me@me.com')
    ->with($productRelation)
    ->get();

// And then get the data like this
$orders->{$productRelation};
```

But for me it is totally fine!